# Can someone please tell me where my 1.4gb ish has gone?

Tags: pi-3, storage

this is probably a really noobish or simple answer question but I am Stumped.

I have SSH'd into my raspberry pi 3 which is running the latest retropie.

I have attached a screenprint of the storage information of my Raspberry pi as I am missing 1.4gb. It says that /dev/root has 15gb total yet only 8.3gb is used and 5.3gb is free (8.3gb + 5.3gb = 13.6gb which is not 15gb).

I even added up everything from the tmpfs stuff it all adds to 15gb, but seeing as all that temp stuff is in /dev anyway isn't it already counted in the 8.3gb.

please help kind regards

Leo

PS I hope I haven't made a right noob of myself lol.
[image: Raspberry Pi Storage Information]

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't "gone" anywhere.

The `ext4` filesystem reserves space for various purposes, including inodes, hash tree, journal and just "reserved" (for performance reasons - to prevent the system filling up, and crashing).

Your calculation is incorrect, as you added rounded human readable sizes. Storage is allocated in blocks (typically 4k), so you should look at these.

The `tempfs` does not use any space on the SD Card.

If you examine the output of the following, it will give you detail of your filesystem

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

If you wish to delve further into how `ext4` works start with https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

Comment: Thankyou for the information.

I understand I used the wrong word. Allocated probably would have been a better term to use.

I tried your terminal command line and do not know what i am looking at lol. Also I have added extra stuff to my Install and now it looks different.

although now it says 15gb, 12gb used and 2.5gb free. Which makes more sense that about 500mb has been allocated/reserved etc.

As much as i have knowledge of Linux I still am no where near a novice in regards to it lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper breakdown of your block devices it's partitions on linux, you can try: `lsblk`. This is part of the `util-linux` package.

As @Milliways already mentioned, the `ext4` filesystem reserved some space for various reasons. By default this is 5%, so for you this should be 0,8 GB. Although this can be larger if defined.

It is also possible that some storage is appointed to SWAP, if you execute `grep swap /etc/fstab` you can check what partition or file is appointed to represent the swap.

You can also check `free -m | grep Swap` to see how large the SWAP actually is.

The reason why this happens is because the system needs a fail safe to report if something terrible has happened.

Comment: Thankyou for the information I tried your command line  free -m | grep swap and nothing happened but as i mentioned in a comment above to the previous comment I am now only not able to find about 500mb which I can more than happily accept as reserved/allocated.

I know that I do not know everything about linux so now i have a little bit more information.

PS how did you get your paragraph breaks mine don't seem to work. Did you use the /n html stuff?

Comment: @LeoPGiles you need to add another space after you've completed a paragraph. Also if you found this answer helpful, please upvote it or mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Raspbian (and AFAIK all OS using SD Cards) **DO NOT** use swap partitions (as noted in fstab).

Comment: @Milliways they do not by default, but to say that they do not or never use it, is incorrect. It is not recommended because it can wear out the SD card.